# Переписать класс Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Вопрос полагаю не тривиальный)
Есть метод в классе  WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker, выглядит он так

```
class WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker extends Walker {

public function start_el( &$output, $cat, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
    $cat_id = intval( $cat->term_id );

    $output .= '<li class="cat-item test cat-item-' . $cat_id;

    if ( $args['current_category'] === $cat_id ) {
        $output .= ' current-cat';
    }

    if ( $args['has_children'] && $args['hierarchical'] && ( empty( $args['max_depth'] ) || $args['max_depth'] > $depth + 1 ) ) {
        $output .= ' cat-parent';
    }

    if ( $args['current_category_ancestors'] && $args['current_category'] && in_array( $cat_id, $args['current_category_ancestors'], true ) ) {
        $output .= ' current-cat-parent';
    }

    $output .= '"><a href="' . get_term_link( $cat_id, $this->tree_type ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'list_product_cats', $cat->name, $cat ) . '</a>';

    if ( $args['show_count'] ) {
        $output .= ' <span class="count">(' . $cat->count . ')</span>';
    }
}


}
```

я хочу переписать этот класс, но не могу понять как это сделать не в папке плагина, а внутри моего файла function, пробовал расширить класс такого плана

```
class My_class extends WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker {

public function start_el( &$output, $cat, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
    $cat_id = intval( $cat->term_id );

    $output .= '<li class="cat-item test cat-item-' . $cat_id;

    if ( $args['current_category'] === $cat_id ) {
        $output .= ' current-cat';
    }

    if ( $args['has_children'] && $args['hierarchical'] && ( empty( $args['max_depth'] ) || $args['max_depth'] > $depth + 1 ) ) {
        $output .= ' cat-parent';
    }

    if ( $args['current_category_ancestors'] && $args['current_category'] && in_array( $cat_id, $args['current_category_ancestors'], true ) ) {
        $output .= ' current-cat-parent';
    }

    $output .= '"><a href="' . get_term_link( $cat_id, $this->tree_type ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'list_product_cats', $cat->name, $cat ) . '</a>';

    if ( $args['show_count'] ) {
        $output .= ' <span class="count">(' . $cat->count . ')</span>';
    }
}


}
```

, но сайт отваливается, можете ткнуть носом, куда смотреть? Заранее спасибо!

PS Объясню, что я вообще хочу сделать) Мне надо в меню вывести описание категории, меню я вывожу в сайдаре, используя виджет Категории товаров

При копировании класса к себе в файл function, я переношу следующий код

```
    class WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker extends Walker {

    /**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $tree_type = 'product_cat';

    /**
     * DB fields to use.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'parent',
        'id'     => 'term_id',
        'slug'   => 'slug',
    );

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     * @since 2.1.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth Depth of category. Used for tab indentation.
     * @param array  $args Will only append content if style argument value is 'list'.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( 'list' !== $args['style'] ) {
            return;
        }

        $indent  = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $output .= "$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     * @since 2.1.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth Depth of category. Used for tab indentation.
     * @param array  $args Will only append content if style argument value is 'list'.
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( 'list' !== $args['style'] ) {
            return;
        }

        $indent  = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }

    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 2.1.0
     *
     * @param string  $output            Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object  $cat               Category.
     * @param int     $depth             Depth of category in reference to parents.
     * @param array   $args              Arguments.
     * @param integer $current_object_id Current object ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $cat, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        $cat_id = intval( $cat->term_id );

        $output .= '<li class="cat-item cat-item-' . $cat_id;

        if ( $args['current_category'] === $cat_id ) {
            $output .= ' current-cat';
        }

        if ( $args['has_children'] && $args['hierarchical'] && ( empty( $args['max_depth'] ) || $args['max_depth'] > $depth + 1 ) ) {
            $output .= ' cat-parent';
        }

        if ( $args['current_category_ancestors'] && $args['current_category'] && in_array( $cat_id, $args['current_category_ancestors'], true ) ) {
            $output .= ' current-cat-parent';
        }

        $output .= '"><a href="' . get_term_link( $cat_id, $this->tree_type ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'list_product_cats', $cat->name, $cat ) . '</a>';

        if ( $args['show_count'] ) {
            $output .= ' <span class="count">(' . $cat->count . ')</span>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     * @since 2.1.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $cat    Category.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of category. Not used.
     * @param array  $args   Only uses 'list' for whether should append to output.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $cat, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

    /**
     * Traverse elements to create list from elements.
     *
     * Display one element if the element doesn't have any children otherwise,
     * display the element and its children. Will only traverse up to the max.
     * depth and no ignore elements under that depth. It is possible to set the.
     * max depth to include all depths, see walk() method.
     *
     * This method shouldn't be called directly, use the walk() method instead.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param object $element           Data object.
     * @param array  $children_elements List of elements to continue traversing.
     * @param int    $max_depth         Max depth to traverse.
     * @param int    $depth             Depth of current element.
     * @param array  $args              Arguments.
     * @param string $output            Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @return null Null on failure with no changes to parameters.
     */
    public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output ) {
        if ( ! $element || ( 0 === $element->count && ! empty( $args[0]['hide_empty'] ) ) ) {
            return;
        }
        parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }
}
```

UPD
Ошибка после добавления в папку mu-plugins

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker' not found in /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/my-wc-walker.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-settings.php(340): include_once() #1 /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-config.php(95): require_once('/home/c/cowboy/...') #2 /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/c/cowboy/...') #3 /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/c/cowboy/...') #4 /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/c/cowboy/...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/my-wc-walker.php on line 3
```

---

> Создайте файл с любым именем, например, my-wc-walker.php в папке wp-content/mu-plugins. Если такой папки нет, создаёте её. Вставьте код класса WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker в этот файл (добавив первую строчку <?php).

В итоге я добавил файлы как вы рекомендовали, но на странице все равно вылетала ошибка

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker, because the name is already in use in /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/walkers/class-wc-product-cat-list-walker.php on line 0
```

То есть после уже моего класса, проверка шла дальше и ругалась уже на класс плагина, сейчас я добавил в начале ту же проверку, что была у начального класса только с одним изменением, я заменил false на true, подскажите, это верное решение ?

```
if ( class_exists( 'WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker', true ) ) {
return;}
```

Comment: Виджет "категория товаров" выводится классом WC_Product_Cat_Dropdown_Walker

Answer (score 2):

К счастью, файл класса содержит конструкцию

```
if ( class_exists( 'WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker', false ) ) {
    return;
}
```

Это означает, что его можно объявить в своём коде. Скопируйте код класса прямо с тем же самым именем `WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker` в `functions.php` и исправьте так, как вам нужно.

**Update**

В связи с противоречащими друг другу ошибками, которые приведены ниже в комментариях, предлагаю более радикальный сценарий.

Создайте файл с любым именем, например, `my-wc-walker.php` в папке `wp-content/mu-plugins`. Если такой папки нет, создаёте её. Вставьте код класса `WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker` в этот файл (добавив первую строчку `<?php`).

MU-плагины (must use plugins) грузятся всегда раньше любых обычных плагинов. Таким образом, ваша версия класса будет загружен однозначно раньше WC и не будет фатальной ошибки `Cannot declare class WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker, because the name is already in use in`.

Comment: Когда просто копирую класс в свой файл, то сайт полностью отваливается. В коде ни чего не меняю, просто копирую его в свой файл и на этом крах.

Comment: Я не знаю, как вы его копируете и что ещё есть в файле. Я проверял, копируя в тему twentytwentyone. Всё работает. Вы сообщение об ошибке из лога покажите.

Comment: Добавил вывод в тело вопроса. Вот такую ошибку выдает система. Это происходит только на той странице где выведен сайдбар, остальные страницы работают корректно

Comment: @Cowboy [https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/wp-debug](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/wp-debug)

Comment: Проше прощения.
Вот код ошибки
`Fatal error: Cannot declare class WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker, because the name is already in use in /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/walkers/class-wc-product-cat-list-walker.php on line 0`
ТАк же есть подобный запрос 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901408/best-way-to-override-the-woocommerce-category-list-walker
при добавлении кода с данной ссылки, выдает следующую ошибку 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker' not found in /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-content/....`

Comment: Два сообщения об ошибке противоречат друг другу. Первое говорит о том, что код WC виджета грузится раньше functions.php, а второе - позже. Так не бывает.

Comment: И вот именно второе сообщение я вижу у себя, когда пытаюсь вставить код из вопроса 32901408 на SO. Какая версия WooCommerce и что за тема у вас?

Comment: Добрый день!  Версия 5.5.2 , добавил по вашей рекомендации папку mu-plugins, в ней в файле my-wc-walker.php прописал код из вопроса 32901408 и система так же выдала ошибку, полный код ошибки добавил в тело вопроса.

Comment: А зачем вы туда невесть что добавили из другого вообще вопроса? Я вам что написал в своём ответе?

Comment: Если я копирую код класса, то выдается вот такая ошибка Fatal error: Cannot declare class WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker, because the name is already in use in /home/c/cowboy/bestguys.ru/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/walkers/class-wc-product-cat-list-walker.php on line 0

Comment: Код класса начинается со строки `class... {` и заканчивается парной скобкой `}`. Не надо в mu-plugin тащить if.